# How to clear EhCache Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to clear Hibernate cache, but I can't get the Ehcache context to clear it. 
Thanks in advance.

**CacheConfiguration.java**,

```
public class CacheConfiguration {

    private final javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> jcacheConfiguration;

    public CacheConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        JHipsterProperties.Cache.Ehcache ehcache = jHipsterProperties.getCache().getEhcache();

        jcacheConfiguration = Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(
                CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class,
                        ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(ehcache.getMaxEntries()))
                        .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.ofSeconds(ehcache.getTimeToLiveSeconds())))
                        .build());
    }

    @Bean
    public JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer() {
        return cm -> {
            createCache(cm, co.interedes.repository.UserRepository.USERS_BY_LOGIN_CACHE);
            createCache(cm, co.interedes.repository.UserRepository.USERS_BY_EMAIL_CACHE);
            cm.createCache(co.interedes.domain.EntityAuditEvent.class.getName(), jcacheConfiguration);
            // jhipster-needle-ehcache-add-entry
        };
    }

 private void createCache(javax.cache.CacheManager cm, String cacheName) {
        javax.cache.Cache<Object, Object> cache = cm.getCache(cacheName);
        if (cache != null) {
            cm.destroyCache(cacheName);
        }
        cm.createCache(cacheName, jcacheConfiguration);
    }
}
```

In this post https://www.journaldev.com/2969/hibernate-caching-first-level-cache clear the first level, but in Jhipster the config its different

Comment: Please provide the errors you have encountered. Also add more tags so the question is visible to a larger audience

Comment: I'm working with liquibase migration, so I changed a entity column, so Ehcache save old columns names, and now hibernate didn't find the new column

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column rolpermiso0_.authority_name does not exist`

Comment: I renamed *authority_name* column to *authority*